# Get access to setText to a view that is not in the default XML layout

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, settext

I want to `.setText` to a view that is not in the default XML layout - `activity_main.xml`.

For a better understanding, I have 2 layout's: `activity_main.xml` and `popup_window.xml`.

The `TextView` is in the `popup_window.xml`.

Comment: How are you displaying `popup_window.xml` if it's not the layout of your activity?

Comment: @Ran With a `PopupWindow`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextID);
    tv.setText()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout ll = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.popup_window, null )
TextView tv = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
tv.setText("Your text here");
customView.addView(ll);
```

Or if you want to use that layout as content view for a dialog ( i assume) then add it this way:

```
dialog.setView(ll);
dialog.show();
```

**<<<<< EDIT: >>>>>**

Ok so if I understood from your comment, that layout is part of a predefined dialog. then simply:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
tv.setText("My text here");
```